# system.identityModel not detected in web.config

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, wif, claims-based-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.0 project running. When I add the ClaimsPrinciplePermission attribute to my action methods I get the following error when navigating to any action method having that attribute.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ID7024: Use of ClaimsPrincipalPermission
>   attribute has been attempted and possibly there is no
>    configuration section defined, see inner
>   exception for details. Also make sure a ClaimsAuthorizationManager
>   element is defined under the  section.

This is the inner exception

> ID7027: Could not load the identity configuration because no
>    configuration section was found.

This is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection,  System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>

  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <claimsAuthorizationManager type="wApp.ClaimManager, wApp" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>  

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>




</configuration>
```

As you can see, I have added all the required sections. The same code and configuration works well in my MVC 5 projects and also my Web Api project. Is there something different to be done in Asp.Net Core projects?

I have also added the required DLL references in the Core 1.0 MVC project as well duplicated the same configuration sections in the App.config file under the core 1.0 MVC project. Still getting the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you configure identity in your startup class ? .Net Core doesn't read the web.config file

Comment: AFAIK, ASP .NET Core rely on `project.json` as its configuration file, neither `web.config` nor `app.config` file was used. Add all `IdentityModel` references to the project file and ensure related dependencies available.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you mean appsettings.json? I don't know how to convert the configsections in the config file to the json format. There is no example of it that I can find. If the web.config doesn't work then why is it provided in the project when you create a new aspnetcore project?

Comment: @aguafrommars do you have an example of configuring identity in startup class ? also an example of the configuration file that .NET Core would require for the same?

Comment: Probably this may help: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html. Both `appsettings.json` and `project.json` contents are important in ASP .NET Core context, try adding your assembly reference to those files instead using XML config.

Comment: Please use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] instead of [tag:asp.net-mvc6].

Answer (score 2):

ClaimsPrincipalPermission, and WIF/System.IdentityModel is not part of .NET Core at all. I'm surprised that even compiles.

From the comments it appears you're parsing a JWT, presumably with the JWT bearer token middleware.

So, all identities in ASP.NET Core are ClaimsIdentities. You can go for [Simple claims based checks](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html), or, more fully to [code expressed policies](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html) which give a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Whats the equivalent then? I have web api that uses claims based approach to authentication. I was planning on reusing the same approach on the core project as well so I could share the libraries and use the same secret key on both projects. the web api project is already in use. Should I drop using asp.net core altogether and just go with MVC 5 if there is no equivalent as yet?

Comment: What do you mean claims based? Are you meaning WS-Fed and SAML, or just some identity based on ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: Theres so many different projects to choose from in the templates and no clear path between what to choose and what to avoid. The docs seem incomplete or outdated

Comment: If you can't explain what you actually want here, then I can't give you any guidance. It looks like from config you want federation, but federation with *what*? And what protocols are in use?

Comment: Identity based on claims principle. Actually I have a working project that uses the standard Asp.Net WebApplication template under framework 4.5. in VS 2013. I am trying to port the UI part of the project to AspnetCore keeping the Service part unchanged and running into these issues.

Comment: Where does the login come from? Local database? An ADFS server? Azure AD?

Comment: local database used by the service generates the jwt token. The token generated by this service is used successfully in MVC5 based projects. In the aspnet core project, the issues I am facing are related to porting the required config sections and configuring identity up in the startup class. Well the start up class configuration is a separate issue. Right now getting the appropriate config sections moved to appsettings.json is what I want help about. Specifically the `configSections`, `system.identityModel.services` and the `system.identityModel` bit

Comment: Solved this by putting all the web.config sections in app.config

Comment: @blowdart - ok, let's say login comes from ADFS. How to emulate working with ADFS from localhost in .NET Core? Thanks.

Comment: can you post how it looks like in app.config?